# Replacement for join from multiprocessing in AsyncWebsocketConsumer

Tags: python-multiprocessing, django-channels

I have an **AsyncWebsocketConsumer** in my Django/Channels webapp that takes care of extensive and longlasting database operations:

```
class dbcompress(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
```

The **receive()** method looks (roughly) like this:

```
async def receive(self, text_data):
  params = loads(text_data)['data'] 
  outlist = {'tracker' : loads(text_data)['tracker']}   

  if params['command'] == 'checkolddb':
    # Do something and return the data to the client]
    outlist['data'] = 'Results'
    await self.send(dumps(outlist)) 

  elif params['command'] == 'fixolddb': 
    myproc = Process(target=fixolddb, args=(params['school'], self.olddbddict[params['school']]))
    myproc.start()
    myproc.join()
    outlist['data'] = 'OK'
    await self.send(dumps(outlist))
```

Because the database operation **fixolddb()** takes long time and blocks the process it runs in, I have moved it to a separate process:

```
def fixolddb(myschool, set_to_fix):
  # Do a lot of things with myschool and set_to_fix, here simply replaced with:
  sleep(2)
```

This runs nicely as long as the time used by **fixolddb()** is short, like the 2 seconds in my example. If **fixolddb()** takes longer (like 60 seconds) channels disconnects the websocket connection and the feedback to the client fails. So I add a ping-thing to my consumers **connect()**:

```
async def ping_loop(self):
  #global started
  started = True
  while started:
    await asyncio.sleep(10)  # Send a Ping every 10 seconds
    await self.send('Ping')

async def connect(self):
  await self.accept()
  asyncio.ensure_future(self.ping_loop())
```

This also runs as designed, until **receive()** is called with **params['command'] == 'fixolddb'**. As soon as this happens, my server stops pinging again. After fixolddb() is done, pinging resumes. From my research I learned that **join()** from **multiprocessing** blocks my async thread. What can I use as replacement to avoid this?

I have varied many things in my process, following recommendations and hints from the Internet. The code I am showing here is as close as I can get to the solution.

**I continued trying and found a solution easier then I thought:**
I changed the relevant receive-section to this:

```
  elif params['command'] == 'fixolddb': 
    myproc = Process(target=fixolddb, args=(params['school'], self.olddbddict[params['school']]))
    myproc.start()
    while myproc.is_alive():
      await asyncio.sleep(1)
    outlist['data'] = 'OK'
    await self.send(dumps(outlist))
```

After that I could also remove the ping thing without any problem...